# Applying R functions as defined in metadata dataframe to specific columns of different dataframes

Tags: r

I have a metadata dataframe that looks like:

```
tablename  variable        applicablefunction   
table1     address_key     myfunc1          
table1     address_key     myfunc2          
table1     zipcode         myfunc1                     
table2     address_key     myfunc3
```

Table 1 looks like

```
address_key  zipcode
234567       560100
123456       560100
453678       560100
```

Table 2 looks like

```
address_key  zipcode
234567       560100
123456       560100
453678       560100
```

Is it possible to get output in below format?

```
tablename  variable        applicablefunction   functionOutput
table1     address_key     myfunc1            98.5
table1     address_key     myfunc2            67.2
table1     zipcode         myfunc1            100.0
table2     address_key     myfunc3            22.8
```

Earlier I tried using:

```
lapply(as.character(metadata$tablename), function(dfname)    metadata$applicablefunction(get(dfname)))
```

But it doesn't seem to work!

I also tried

```
do.call(metadata$applicablefunction, metadata$tablename)
```

But I guess I am not on the right track! Much thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: If `Table 1`, `Table 2` and possible `Table X` all have the same structure (like in your example), `rbind()`ing them to one `data.frame` with an additional column stating whether the data comes from `Table 1` or `Table 2` would make this a bit more straight forward. Maybe you could clarify if it is a requirement, that `Table 1` and `Table2` have to be single objects.

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Hi @ottlngr , your approach would work too. Table1, Table2,...Tablex can be binded with with an additional column stating whether the data comes from Table 1 or Table 2 or table x. Is it possible to get the above output then?

Comment: @Roland if you could please explain how? I am new to R and not very sure of how to achieve this?

Comment: Please add a reproductible example, an some code attempt from you..

Comment: @DebanjanGhosal  if you want help, you should first show that you've tried something..

Comment: @timat .. Sure. But before downvoting questions understand the situation first. U could have told the same without downvoting. People with knowledge dosn't show ego like you did! Shows your true identity. Will post what I have tried in few seconds.

Comment: @DebanjanGhosal Sorry but i did not downvote actually..

Comment: Not the downvoter but have in mind that the most frequent reasons that a Q is downvoted are: 1) No reproducible Example. 2) No effort in solving prior to posting here.

Comment: So, a) I have definitely posted a reproducible example with all parts and pieces. b) I have just added what I have tried.

Comment: Well technically you didn't. `dput` will create a reproducible example. And the downvote came before posting your attempt. Anyway, 1 downvote is not a big deal anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I made a reproducible example myself. This comes close to what you asked for (before you updated the post):

`rbind` the single tables:

```
t1 <- data.frame(table = "Table1",
                 address_key = c(234567, 123456, 45678),    
                 zipcode = c(560100, 560100, 560100))
t2 <- data.frame(table = "Table2", 
                 address_key = c(234567, 123456, 45678), 
                 zipcode = c(560100, 560100, 560100))

t <- rbind(t1, t2)
```

There is your meta table (I take explicit functions for demonstration):

```
meta <- data.frame(tablename = c("Table1", "Table1", "Table1", "Table2"),
                   variable = c("address_key", "address_key", "zipcode", "address_key"),
                   applyFun = c("sum", "mean", "sum", "median"),
                   value = NA)
```

Then loop through the rows and use `if ... else` to apply the desired functions:

```
for (i in 1:dim(meta)[1]) {
  sub <- t[t$table == meta[i, ]$tablename, as.character(meta[i, ]$variable)]
  res <- if (meta[i,]$applyFun == "sum") {
    sum(sub)
  } else if (meta[i,]$applyFun == "mean") {
    mean(sub)
  } else if (meta[i,]$applyFun == "median") {
    median(sub)
  }
  meta[i,]$value <- res
}
```

This gives:

```
  tablename    variable applyFun   value
1    Table1 address_key      sum  403701
2    Table1 address_key     mean  134567
3    Table1     zipcode      sum 1680300
4    Table2 address_key   median  123456
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm. I will make sure to post properly from next time. I need to learn a lot and I am in the process. Thanks for acknowledging the same.

Comment: That's way to roundabout. Just use `getFunction(meta[i,]$applyFun)(sub)` instead of your `if` conditions.

Comment: Indeed, given explicit function names are given in `meta$applyFun` (as is in my example).